# Java Calendar - issue with getting correct date

Tags: java, calendar

i need to parse date

date is in format:

```
2014-05-21 04:15:00.0
```

When i'm trying to parse it, i get stange informations:

```
    java.util.Calendar calendarEventStart = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendarEventStart.setTime(dateStart);

    parseDateToCalendar.setYearStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.YEAR));
    parseDateToCalendar.setMonthStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.MONTH));
    parseDateToCalendar.setDayStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    parseDateToCalendar.setHourStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    parseDateToCalendar.setMonthStart(calendarEventStart.get(calendarEventStart.MINUTE));
```

Display:

```
parseDateToCalendar.getYearStart() = 2014 - THIS IS OK (YEAR)
parseDateToCalendar.getMonthStart() = 30 - !!WRONG - THIS SHOULD BE MINUTE
parseDateToCalendar.getDayStart() = 21 - THIS IS OK (DAY)
parseDateToCalendar.getHourStart() = 4 - !!WRONG - THIS SHOULD BE MONTH
parseDateToCalendar.getMinuteStart() = 0 - !!WRONG - HERE SHOULD BE VALUE FROM MONTH
```

Could you help me, what is wrong ?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `SimpleDateFormat`? What is `dateStart`? What is `parseDateToCalendar`? Your question is very unclear. It would be helpful if you could show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I would check your `DateFormat` pattern as it's probably not returning the `Date` object you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just mixed up the method names,

```
parseDateToCalendar.getYearStart() = 2014 - THIS IS OK (YEAR)
parseDateToCalendar.getMinuteStart() = 30 - CORRECT - THIS SHOULD BE MINUTE
parseDateToCalendar.getDayStart() = 21 - THIS IS OK (DAY)
parseDateToCalendar.getMonthStart() = 4 - CORRECT - THIS SHOULD BE MONTH
// 'Value from Month?'
// parseDateToCalendar.getMinuteStart() = 0 - !!WRONG - HERE SHOULD BE VALUE FROM MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the usual way to parse a date in Java, for your date format :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
Date date = sdf.parse("2014-05-21 04:15:00.0");
```

See the `SimpleDateFormat`javadoc for more info : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

How did you get the `dateStart` value?

I'd recommend using java's [SimpleDataFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the string. The format string should be `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S`

P.S check out [the new time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) in java8. More convenient than good ol' Calendar

Answer (score 0):

dateStart must be a java.util.Date . Have you tried printing it out using dateStart.toString()?

My guess is the Calendar is wrong because the Date is wrong, and the Date is wrong because it expects a different format than you are using. Perhaps you coulduse a DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat to specify the format the string is in, as in this example.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/